# Need 'ping' output including date/time, source IP address, target IP address, low/high/average latency and packet loss in a CSV file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get to a point where I have a .csv file including the following information in one line

- Date/Time
- SourceIP
- TargetIP
- Low/High/Average latency
- Packet Loss

The following command is useful as it returns some detail regarding the low/high and average response times.

```
Test-Connection $Address -Count 1 | 
    Measure-Object ResponseTime -Minimum -Average -Maximum |
    Export-Csv -Path $FilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Returns:

```
Average  Maximum  Minimum  Property
-------  -------  -------  --------
14            14       14  ResponseTime
```

This command is also useful but doesn't provide the detail on response times

```
Test-Connection $Address -Count 1 |
    Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, IPV4Address, ResponseTime |
    Export-Csv -Path $FilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Returns:

```
PSComputerName  IPV4Address  ResponseTime
--------------  -----------  ------------
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  8.8.4.4                23
```

Is there a way of displaying all information in a CSV file on one line, also including the hosts IP address?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```
$Response = Test-Connection $Address -Count 1
$ResponseTimeMetrics = $Response | Measure-Object ResponseTime -Minimum -Maximum -Average
$ResponseObject = $Response | Select-Object `
    PSComputerName,IPv4Address,ResponseTime,
    @{name="Minimum";Expression={$ResponseTimeMetrics.Minimum}},
    @{name="Maximum";Expression={$ResponseTimeMetrics.Maximum}},
    @{name="Average";Expression={$ResponseTimeMetrics.Average}}
$ResponseObject | Export-CSV -Path $FilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

The `$response` variable is storing the `Test-Connection` results. `$ResponseTimeMetrics` is storing the average, minimum, and maximum values you want from the `Measure-Object` command. `$ResponseObject` selects properties already provided by the object stored in `$Response` and then adding properties from the `$ResponseTimeMetrics` assigned object. I am using hash tables to add the custom properties to `$ResponseObject`, so that I can easily name the  properties to my liking and provide a value that is not coming from the pipeline.

You can see [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) for more information on creating and retrieving object properties with `Select-Object`.

Comment: You can safely remove the backticks in lines 4,5 and 6.

Comment: AdminOfThings, thanks very much indeed. Not just for providing the solution, but for the clear explanation of the logic. It works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks also to Theo